# what is the use of -U option in ping command?

Tags: linux, unix, ping

I am learning about the ping command and their options.

Can anyone please explain me what is the difference between the below two 
outputs ?

```
$ ping 192.168.2.2
PING 192.168.2.2 (192.168.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.187 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.197 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.203 ms
^C
--- 192.168.2.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.187/0.195/0.203/0.017 ms

$ ping -U 192.168.2.2
PING 192.168.2.2 (192.168.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.202 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.418 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.230 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.283 ms
^C
--- 192.168.2.2 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.202/0.283/0.418/0.083 ms
```

If there is no difference between these two outputs, then what is the use -U option in ping command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

th -U option 
Print full user-to-user latency (the old behaviour). Normally ping prints network round trip time, which can be different f.e. due to DNS failures.

ping -U is different for example if your DNS server do not resolve the hostname and your computer needto to ask to the secondary DNS, this kind of "latency" is measured from ping -U, else is ignored from ping without -U

Comment: what is the meaning of full user to user latency ?

Comment: Llatency is the time measured from ping, the time required for the communication. Latency, is the amount of time it takes for the water that enters the pipe at one end to exit at the other. If your pipe is just a few feet long, water exits the bottom of the pipe almost as quickly as it flows into the top. If the pipe is 50 to 100 feet long, it’ll take several seconds before the water starts to flow.

Comment: In output how can I test the difference between ping and ping -U ?

Comment: ping -U is different for example if your DNS server do not resolve the hostname and your computer needto to ask to the secondary DNS, this kind of "latency" is measured from ping -U, else is ignored from ping without -U